# How do I view and edit the data in a Microsoft Azure SQL Database?

Tags: swift, azure, azure-sql-database

I have just started to use Microsoft Azure as a mobile backend service for an iOS Swift app. I have created a new SQL Database on the Azure Portal and I am able to insert and query data from it via my app, but I cannot view or edit the information that I have inserted in my database. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Download the SQL Server Management Tools to connect and query the database.  http://downloadsqlserverexpress.com/

Comment: Are you running into a specific issue? Have you tried connecting using the credentials for your database?

Comment: You shouldn't be talking directly to your database.  Put a webservice inbetween.  For example, have some PHP files on the webserver that are able to talk to the database, and your app talks to those PHP files.   That way, if you ever want to change to PostgreSQL, for example, or you move your database to some other hosted platform, you just change those PHP files accordingly and don't have to push a new version of your app, and then hope people upgrade.

Comment: Download the latest update of SQL Management Studio 2016 older versions doesn't support data edit  data https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From your Azure Portal, navigate to App Services then your mobile app. Under settings locate the Mobile section then click on Easy tables.Then you can click on your table and a new blade will slide in with all the columns displayed and any data you have. Hope that helps.

Edit: the Easy Tables is only supported for Node.js backends. You need SSMS to view the data with a .Net backend